# PHP - Why my function isnt returning anything

Tags: php, function

I have function calling itself. There is a number of max repeats and repeat counter. The function is calling itself until reaching a point where repeat counter is equal to max repeats. If I uncomment messages inside a function, I can see everything working as it should. But if I want to return an array of positions, there is no result:

```
function myFunction($positions, $maxRepeats, $repeatCounter = 0){

    if($repeatCounter < $maxRepeats){
        // echo 'Test message - loop ' . $repeatCounter;

        $positions[] = array('title' => $repeatCounter);
        $repeatCounter++;
        myFunction($positions,$maxRepeats,$repeatCounter);

    } else {

        // echo 'Test message - end ' . $repeatCounter;
        return $positions;

    }

}

$positions = array();
$result = myFunction($positions,2);

print_r($result);
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Because if this condition is true:

```
if($repeatCounter < $maxRepeats)
```

Then the function never encounters a `return` statement.  It looks like you meant to return the recursive result:

```
return myFunction($positions,$maxRepeats,$repeatCounter);
```